# SNMPGet over IPv6

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, snmp

So I am trying to do an snmpget via ipv6.  Here are a few commands I've tried:

```
snmpget -v 1 -c public 'fdab:3bce:6c78:1:215:5dff:fe00:3914' sysUpTime.0
snmpget -v 1 -c public 'udp6:fdab:3bce:6c78:1:215:5dff:fe00:3914' sysUpTime.0
snmpget -v 1 -c public 'udp6:[fdab:3bce:6c78:1:215:5dff:fe00:3914]' sysUpTime.0
snmpget -v 1 -c public 'udp6:[fdab:3bce:6c78:1:215:5dff:fe00:3914]:161' sysUpTime.0
snmpget -v 1 -c public 'udp6:[fdab:3bce:6c78:1:215:5dff:fe00:3914%eth0]:161' sysUpTime.0
```

These responses result in `Timeout: No Response from udp6:[fdab:3bce:6c78:1:215:5dff:fe00:3914].` or some variation of that sort.

I know snmp is working:

```
snmpget -v 1 -c public '127.0.0.1' sysUpTime.0
```

Results in: `DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (51895) 0:08:38.95`

Within my /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf I've tried without an `agentaddress` (default for Ubuntu) or by setting it's value to 161 / 161,udp6 / upd6 / updv6 or many other variations.

My concern is perhaps Ubuntu's snmp isn't compiled with ipv6 support?  How would I find that out?

Further information:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS
Release:        10.04
Codename:       lucid
```

I am up to date and I am using the snmp snmpd packages.  I also have a working ipv6 network and I can actually snmpget a windows machine via it's ipv6 address.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic diagnosis steps should see this one solved:

- Is `snmpd` listening on IPv6?  (`netstat -lun |grep :161`)
- Is the firewall configured to allow the traffic in?  (`ip6tables -L -n`)
- Does `snmpd` see the traffic, and does it appear to do something useful with it?  (`strace -p <snmpd PID>`; check logs).

Comment: 1.  both udp and udp6 are listening on :161.  2.  no firewall is enabled  3.  snmpd does see traffic but not 100% sure what I am looking for.

Comment: I'm leaning towards not compiled with IPv6 support.  Looks like I might have to build it by source.

Comment: If it's not compiled with IPv6 support, how's it listening on udp6?

Comment: Good point, I can certainly ask another system via ipv6 but asking myself in ipv6 seems to be something it isn't up for.  I'm scouring the conf files searching for the key here.

Comment: Have you set any ACLs that might be v4-only?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.  A very default install.

Comment: Thanks to you and http://www.sendai.wide.ad.jp/IPv6/net-snmp/index_e.html I found the key!  In /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf you need `com2sec6 readonly  default         public`.  Notice the `com2sec6` instead of `com2sec`.  Thanks for your help!  Couldn't of done it without ya.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

### snmpd.conf config:

/etc/snmp/snmp.conf:

```
agentaddress  udp:127.0.0.1:161,udp:192.168.1.2:161,udp6:[::1]:161,udp6:[2001:370:2d4e:8::9]:161
```

### Form of `snmpget` command:

```
snmpget -v2c -c public "udp6:[2001:370:2d4e:8::9]:161" SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0
```

### Returns:

```
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (1498) 0:00:14.98
```

### Version:

`dpkg -l | grep snmpd`

```
ii  snmpd   5.9.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2   arm64   SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) agents
```